# Apply transparency with convert command

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, opacity

I have this two pictures http://s29.postimg.org/6j5m4jyx3/frame_0.png and http://s14.postimg.org/zdfn4f84x/frame_2.png and I need to mix both into a new picture with first at back and second at front with opacity at 70%.

To do it, I have this commands:

```
convert frame-2.png -background transparent -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 70% frame-1.png
composite -background transparent -gravity center frame-1.png frame-0.png frame-1.png
```

Result is like I want but transparency to frame-2.png is applied with a strange way. I don't understand why transparent background also get a "black" opacity http://s27.postimg.org/bst4fmnhv/frame_1.png

Result should be http://s28.postimg.org/pb1ee1egt/frame_1.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution is using

```
-evaluate Divide 1.5
```

instead

```
-evaluate set 70%
```

And with this way, transparecy is applied perfect :)